# with the help of Mirth Connect is it possible get data from Multi-para monitors used in hospitals

Tags: java, device, hl7, mirth, health-monitoring

Want to fetch / get data from Multi-para patient monitor.

can we do these with help of [Mirth Connect](https://www.mirth.com/)

In monitors LAN cable port is available with which we can do these but how we don't know.

So any help how we can do this or how i can find solution of the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with Mirth Connect.
Mirth Connect has an extension to send and receive data over serial communication ports.

> The Serial Connector allows Mirth Connect to send and receive data
>   over serial communication ports, such as those compliant with the
>   RS-232 standards. Any installed transmission mode may be used in
>   conjunction with the connectors, including a raw serial mode, MLLP, or
>   the ASTM E1381 mode. Options are available to select the port to
>   connect to, the baud rate, the parity, and much more, allowing for
>   fully customizable communication.

If your monitor doesn't have serial connector you can link via a RS232 to a RJ45.